# Bitwise AND operation with a signed byte

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

Here is the code:

```
int i = 200;
byte b = (byte) 200;
System.out.println(b);
System.out.println((short) (b));
System.out.println((b & 0xff));
System.out.println((short) (b & 0xff));
```

Here is the output:

```
-56
-56
200
200
```

Bitwise AND with 0xff shouldn't have changed anything in `b`, but apparently it does have an effect, why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It has an effect because `200` is beyond the maximum possible (signed) `byte`, `127`.  The value is already assigned `-56` because of this overflow.  The most significant byte, worth `-128`, is set.

```
11001000
```

The first 2 output statements show `-56` because of this, and the fact that casting to a `short` will perform sign extension to preserve negative values.

When you perform `& 0xff`, 2 things happen.  First, the value is promoted to an `int`, with sign extension.

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11001000
```

Then, the bit-and is performed, keeping only the last 8 bits.  Here, the 8th bit is no longer `-128`, but `128`, so `200` is restored.

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 11001000
```

This occurs whether the value is casted to a `short` or not; a `short` has 16 bits and can easily represent `200`.

```
00000000 11001000
```

Answer (score 1):

Java `byte` is a signed type. That is why you see a negative number when you print it: 200, or `0xC8`, is above the largest positive number representable by `byte`, so it gets interpreted as a negative `byte`.

However, `0xff` constant is an `int`. When you perform arithmetic and bitwise logic operations on a `byte` and an `int`<sup>*</sup>, the result becomes an `int`. That is why you see `200` printed in the second set of examples: `(b & 0xff)` produces an integer `200`, which remains `200` after shrinking conversion to `short`, because `200` fits into a `short` without becoming negative.

<sup>*</sup> or another `byte`, for that matter; Java standard specifies a list of conversions that get applied depending on operand types.

Comment: When you perform arithmetic or bitwise operations on two bytes, the result also becomes an int; it makes working with anything smaller than an int really awkward in Java.

Comment: @user2357112 That too. I did not want to confuse OP by mentioning all the conversions. I added a note to explain this.

Comment: @user2357112 ah, this is very annoying indeed.

Answer (score 0):

working with different integer types is a mine field.

for example, what's going on here?

```
byte b = (byte) 200;
```

it's actually equivalent to

```
int i = 200;
byte b = (byte)i;
```

and the narrowing cast `(byte)` simply takes the lowest 8 bits of the `int` value.